# How to delta compress audio track file , video tracks file, full webm file into one zip file?

Tags: compression, zip, 7-zip

Using `yt-dlp -k https://youtu.be/33BT7KIZwTY`,
I downloaded audio and video files and obtained a merged webm file.

After running the command, there are three files:

```
youtube originals [33BT7KIZwTY].f251.webm
youtube originals [33BT7KIZwTY].f303.webm
youtube originals [33BT7KIZwTY].webm
```

What is the optimal way to compress these three files into a zip or 7z?
I tried `7z a video.zip *.webm` but got an 8.48MB zip, indicating no delta compression.

---

PS. Git is very good at handling delta encoding.

I also tried using `git diff --binary '.\youtube originals [33BT7KIZwTY].f303.webm' '.\youtube originals [33BT7KIZwTY].webm'`  , which calculated the difference of the video files and generated a 0.8MB patch file. wow. delta diff.great job,git.

```shell
   806100 2023-03-11 22:49:15.300633700 patch
   582755 2019-12-08 17:29:41.000000000 youtube originals [33BT7KIZwTY].f251.webm
  3898857 2019-12-08 17:35:40.000000000 youtube originals [33BT7KIZwTY].f303.webm
  4481777 2019-12-08 17:29:41.000000000 youtube originals [33BT7KIZwTY].webm
```

---

i also tried `git init`, `git add .`,`git commit`. `git gc`.

Then I got 1 small pack file.

```
.\.git\objects\pack\pack-93ba3cc01cdf5a32cb2281b7529faf3c029cac0f.pack
Total objects: 1 (1)
Total size: 4.275 MiB (4482449 Byte)
```

Comment: According to [this GitHub page](https://techshelps.github.io/WinRAR/html/HELPCompressionAdvanced.htm) ZIP can't do delta compression at all. I can't find a single contradictory resource. "Optimal" is a dicey way to put it - your optimal might not be the same as mine. [RAR has delta option](https://openrarfile.net/advanced_options.html).

Comment: What about 7zip? i tried 7z a video.7z . -mx9 -t7z. but still no delta compress.

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think so. Researching the above I saw it mentioned in several places with note about smaller file sizes compared to zip w/o delta. I saw somewhere a mention of obtaining delta before compression to reduce file sizes, but that was some theoretical study w/o named tools so didn't put that in. I just found out about [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com) SE site (cuz of course there is one :-D), I think that might be a better community for this kind of question. If you move it there, pls delete this as cross-posting is frowned upon.